# Method including SQLConnection - good approach?

Tags: c#, refactoring, sqlconnection

Hey, I currently have this method in my code:

```
public static DataSet PrepareDataSet(some params)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Utils.EscapeProcedureName(...), sqlConnection);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //do some stuff with the adapter using the params

    sqlConnection.Open();
    DataSet dataSet= new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
    sqlConnection.Close();
    return dataSet;
}
```

This code is called from an aspx.cs page. Is it a good approach to have the SQL connection stuff and the adapter inside the method? If not, how can that be refactored? Somehow I think this is not good for testing for example ...

Thanks for ur ideas :)

Comment: It would be better to have a separate, dedicated data-access layer to encapsulate all of this away from the actual ASPX.CS page code. Plus, you should **always** put your `SqlConnection` into `using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection()) { .... }` blocks

Comment: You also need to wrap the creation of the SqlConnection in a 'using' statment, to take account of possible memory leaks.

Comment: only the creation, or the full code down to sqlConnection.Close()?

Comment: The full code to *after* the return. With the using() you also won't need the close as the connection will automatically be closed when control leaves the using block and it gets disposed.

Comment: Thanks, I wrapped the SQL stuff in a using now ...

Answer (score 0):

No it is not good approach to make a data access in from the page code.

Try to make your application in layered approach [N-Tier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-tier), or use [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) Design pattern.

Try to separate the Data Access logic and Business logic in your application so it will be easier for code maintainability and readability; you can even use auto generating tools to increase the code speed and quality by eliminating redundant work.  Read more about [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping);
it will help you a lot about good coding practices.